# Choosing data storage for a web game?

Tags: database

I am creating a game with jQuery and PHP that will simulate The Oregon Trail.

I need an easy way to store the scenarios and the choices. I also need a way that I can pass the choice the user made into a PHP page with a GET variable and have PHP spit out more choices and a new scenario.

I am considering a flat file or SQLite.

What would be the easiest database to do this with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how you want to structure your data.

For example, If you're finding a lot of complex objects a database system with good support for object storage would be best for your application, if there's only a few primitives perhaps storing it all client side in localStorage could be sufficient.

There's a lot of considerations to take when choosing a system and it mostly revolves around what sort of data you want to store and where you want your application to run.